# How can I calculate the median and standard deviation of a bunch stream of numbers in Perl?

Tags: perl, statistics, logging, median

In our logfiles we store response times for the requests.  What's the most efficient way to calculate the median response time, the "75/90/95% of requests were served in less than N time" numbers etc?   (I guess a variation of my question is: What's the best way to calculate the median and standard deviation of a bunch stream of numbers).

The best I came up with was just reading all the numbers, ordering them and then picking out the numbers, but that seems really goofy.  Isn't there a smarter way?

We use Perl, but solutions for any language might be helpful.

Comment: Show a sample of your logfile

Comment: hi spx2 - our logs are just line-terminated JSON structures, where one of the elements is a list of various time counters (actual time, cpu time, etc).  I don't think it's too interesting; we'll do a map-reduce type thing to pull out list of response times (by page type, etc).

Comment: I would have thought with your magic that 110% of the requests were served before they even left the requestor. :)

Comment: Though old: use a tool that's made for this: R. There are R-interfaces for perl, like https://metacpan.org/pod/Statistics::R . Vice versa seems not to be supported: well, prepare files by perl and process them by R ...